# How get plugin to load?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to add the [fastimage plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/fastimage) but it's not working (it doesn't show in the image dialog). Am I adding it incorrectly?

In config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    //Add the fastimage plugin and its dependencies
    config.extraPlugins = 'dialogui,dialog,fastimage';

    ...
}
```

Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't show in the image dialog"? That seems to be a plugin to insert images as base64 data, and that means that the whole content is inserted into the editor. And there are known problems trying to work with that kind of images.

Comment: @AlfonsoML I mean the tab doesn't show in the image dialog. all i see is a place to add a url, not browse for an image

Comment: That's not what this plugin does according to the github code.